# Trying to better understand Unity gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity, gameobject

New to Unity, but develop in C# normally.  I can't seem to get how / why / where to grab certain elements.  For simplicity, I have a top-level game object, say a cube.  I add a sphere to the scene as child to the cube. The child sphere (actually more complex), has navigation mesh, animation object, collider and finally a script in C#.

Now, my C# class is comprised of an instance of an C# class on the class.  Something like

```
public class CMyGeneric
{
   public void someMethod()
   {
      // invalid getting to "gameObject" reference
   }
}


public class CMyMainScript
{
   public CMyGeneric myGeneric;

   void Start()
   {
      myGeneric = new CMyGeneric();
   }

   void Update()
   {
      myGeneric.someMethod();
   }
}
```

So, the parent game object is the cube, the child is the sphere, and the CMyMainScript script is attached to the sphere.  However, when I try to reference "gameObject" via the CMyGeneric (instance), call within the "someMethod", the "someMethod" doesn't appear to see the overall "gameObject".

Now, how/what am I missing as each thing that gets attached, unity adds to these game objects, and I don't know how to get respective hierarchical levels of where things are even though I know where they are from a relative perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you've left out some code? Like that `CMyMainScript` and `CMyGeneric` extends MonoBehaviour? Are you expecting to be able to access `gameObject` inside your `CMyGeneric` class because you'd instantiated it inside another class?

If you want to access `gameObject` you need to attach that script to a game object by using `this.gameObject.AddComponent<CMyGeneric>()`. This returns the reference to `CMyGeneric` that you'd want to use, and will have the `gameObject` reference properly set.

However, if you're attaching `CMyGeneric` as a script you may as well call `someMethod` inside of the `CMyGeneric` `Update()` method.

Alternatively, if you're not making `CMyGeneric` into a script to be attached, and you want `CMyGeneric` to act on a `gameObject`, just pass the game object into the `someMethod` call.

```
public void someMethod(GameObject gameObject)
{
   // valid "gameObject" reference
}
```

And:

```
void Update()
{
   myGeneric.someMethod(this.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Thank you both (including Kelly) for the answers and will try the impact of both (yes, the main class derived from MonoBehavior), and passing the game object is one thing I've done in the past when dealing with desktop WPF applications.  Thanks for the options.

Answer (score 1):

GameObjects are very closely linked to Transforms.

The [GameObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GameObjects.html) could be thought of as a container to hold a set of [Components](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) e.g. scripts, colliders etc.

Meanwhile the [Transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Transforms.html) holds properties than connect the GameObject to the the world e.g. position/scale/rotation and any parent/child relationships.

**Parent:**

When scripting you can access the parent GameObject like this:

```
Transform parent = transform.parent;
parent.gameObject
```

**Children:**

Child GameObjects can be accessed by name (optionally including hierarchy):

```
Transform child =  transform.Find("path/objectname");
child.gameObject
```

Transform also provides `GetEnumerator()` allowing us to iterate through the collection of children:

```
foreach (Transform child in transform)
{
    child.gameObject
}
```

Comment: Thank you both (including Byte56) for the answers and will try the impact of both.  I like how you explained the ability to reference parent / child to go through the connections.